# Grails search list with 'like'

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So I have domain classes

```
class SalesRep {
   SalesTerritory territory
}
class SalesTerritory {
   hasMany=[accounts: AccountCustomer]
   String territoryCode
}

class AccountCustomer {
   String accountName
   String accountCode
   belongsTo = SalesTerritory
   hasMany=[salesTerritories: SalesTerritory]
}
```

In the controller, I can get the accounts by:

```
def salesRep = SalesRep.findBy... // 
def accounts = salesRep.territory.accounts
```

I would like to do two things:

1) Search for accounts with some string (ex. '%My Account%'), something like below:

```
def accounts = salesRep.territory.accounts.find("accountName like '%My Account%'")
```

2) Sort accounts

```
def accounts = salesRep.territory.accounts.sort("accountName")
```

I know I can add static mapping = { sort accountName } in the domain class, but what if I want to sort using a different field such as accountCode. Thanks, I tried using createCriteria, but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you build your criteria and what goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. I couldn't get that to work but one solution I got to work is below, basically using regular expressions.

```
def myAccount = "My Account"
accounts = salesRep.territory.accounts.findAll {
   it.accountName ==~ /(?i).*${myAccount}.*/
}
```

The (?i) makes the match ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def accounts = salesRep.territory.accounts.findAllByAccountNameLike("%${MyAccount}%")
```

Like is case sensitive, but if you want to ignore case, then use iLike.

For sorting you can use

```
def accounts = salesRep.territory.accounts.list(sort:'accountName', order:'asc')
```

You can also define sorting in your domain class via static mapping

```
static mapping = {
     sort accountName:"asc"
}
```

But I think if you want to sort the way you have it you need to add a comparator and make sure your class implements Comparable.

```
class YourClassName implements Comparable{

 String accountName
 ...


 @Override
 public int compareTo(Object o) {
     if (o == null || this == null) {
         return 0;
     } else {
         return value.compareTo(o.value)
     }
 }
}
```

Then when you call .sort it will use the compareTo method in your domain.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use the findAllByAccountNameLike Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.findAllByAccountNameLike() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [%Alleg%]
        at com.eveo.nplate.service.AccountService.getAccountsForUser(AccountService.groovy:25)

Comment: is accountName defined in your domain? If you type .findAllBy and wait a sec it will display a context menu and you should see your variable listed in green.

Comment: Yes, it's defined in the Domain Class AccountCustomer. Maybe this just works if used as AccountCustomer.findAllByAccountNameLike???, but not when it is a list of accounts?

Comment: You could be right. The dynamic finders seem very basic. I am glad you worked it out.